# Committing nested .hg folders

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Forget everything you think you know about sub repositories, sub modules and what not. My problem is very simple.

I have two repositories, repoOne and repoTwo

Contents of repoTwo is only one file: **DefaultConfig.txt**

Contents of repoOne is:

```
+ repoOne
      + folderA
           +folderB 
                  +repoTwo
                       +.hg
                       +DefaultConfig.txt
```

Ok, now I make changes only to **DefaultConfig.txt** within **repoOne**. I also add a sibling file next to it just for fun.

I want those changes to be committed only against **repoOne**.

That is, repoTwo should not know about these changes what so ever, but I want repoOne to keep getting updates if it chooses to hg pull from within repoTwo. It can also commit to it from inside that folder if I choose to do so.

Why is this not possible? Why does mercurial refuse to commit .hg files? It would be so brilliant otherwise! What other versioning control system would support something like this from scratch?

GIT also suffer from this exact problem! Whyyyyy!?

Comment: Mercurial searches upwards for .hg directories to find which repo it's in.  Since it finds `repoTwo/.hg` first, that's the repo it thinks it's in.  Why do you want to commit .hg files?  It's extremely non-standard.

Comment: This is what submodules etc. are *desgined to do*. Why don't you want to use them?

Comment: @StephenRasku Yes, but if I committing from inside repoTwo then I want it to commit only to repoTwo.

Comment: @Chris No, submodules does not allow for what I am talking about. Pay attention to the details, mainly the changes I want to do.

Comment: @SecretService, did you drop an .hg directory into an existing repository?  Based on your layout, DefaultConfig.txt should be in repoTwo (not repoOne).

Comment: Why should we forget all we know about how Mercurial is _supposed to work_?

Comment: @StephenRasku Yes, it is in repoTwo, but I want it to be in repoOne as well. I want to be able to commit them to both at will. If I commit from higher folder then it is repoOne, inside repoTwo then commit to repoTwo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but it seems to me like you just need to specify the repository root directory on the command line, which is something you can do for nearly all `hg` commands:

```
cd repoTwo
hg -R ../../.. add DefaultConfig.txt
hg -R ../../.. commit -m "Whyyyyy would I do this!?"
```

However, I would advise against the structure you're describing, as it will very easily become confused unless you decide to go with [SubRepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository), which are considered a feature of last resort.

---

**Update**: Having played with it, this doesn't actually work, as it reports that the file is in a nested repo.

Attempting to add the file to the nested repository after adding it to the parent, results in it being marked as "removed" from the parent repository.

One possible solution would be to have the file in question being in one nested repository, and cloned to another nested repository:

```
+ parentRepo
  + .hg
  + nestedOne
    + .hg
    + DefaultConfig.txt
  + nestedTwo    : cloned from nestedOne
    + .hg
    + DefaultConfig.txt
```

Something like this would mean that you could have two versions of `DefaultConfig.txt`, and if you make changes to one, you can pass them on to the other by means of `push` and `pull`.  I'm not sure if that's what you want, but it's the closest I could get, and it's messy.

To answer your question "Why is this not possible?", there are several reasons I can think of, but the main one IMO is that if you needed something like what you're asking, then there is likely an issue with your workflow, that will cause confusion down-the-line.

Comment: hmm .. I am quite confused by the virtual relative subrepos stuff ... If you look at my last comment on the question it pretty much describes what I am trying to achieve